# Не понимаю где программа проваливается, квадратные уравнения C++

Tags: c++, олимпиада

**Легенда**

Вася уже подзабыл уроки математики 8ого класса, поэтому хочет научить решать уравнения свой компьютер, чтобы больше не тратить на них время. Помогите ему написать эту программу!

**Формат ввода**

Входной файл содержит три целых числа a, b и c, не превосходящих по модулю 109, — коэффициенты уравнения a x2 + bx + c = 0.

**Формат вывода**

В первой строке вывода требуется указать число различных решений этого уравнения. Далее выведите корни уравнения с точностью до 6 знаков после запятой, по одному в строке. Корни должны следовать в порядке возрастания.

Если корней бесконечно много, выведите ровно одно число, -1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    double a, b, c, d, x, x1, x2;
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    d = b*b - 4 * a * c;
    if (a == 0 && c == 0) {
        cout<<-1;
    }
    else if (a == 0) {
        x = (-c) / b;
        cout<<1<<endl;
        printf("%.6lf", x);
    }
    else if (d>0) {
        x1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / 2 * a;
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / 2 * a;
        cout<<2<<endl;
        printf("%.6lf", min(x1, x2));
        cout<<endl;
        printf("%.6lf", max(x1, x2));
    }
    else if (d == 0) {
        x = (-b) / (2 * a);
        cout<<1;
        cout<<endl;
        printf("%.6lf", x);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: P.S Задача взята с https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/655/enter/
Задача D

Comment: Как минимум `if (a == 0 && c == 0) {
        cout<<-1;
    }` неверно, если `b` - не ноль. Еще - `x1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / 2 * a;` - вообще-то `x1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / 2 / a;` Нет, это все надо переписывать...

Comment: При каких условиях, корней бесконечно много, при a=b=c=0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, например, вот так -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    long long a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%lld %lld %lld",&a,&b,&c);
    d = b*b-4*a*c;

    if (a == 0 && b == 0) puts(c ? "0" : "-1");
    else if (a == 0)      printf("1\n%.7lf\n", -((double)c)/b);
    else if (d == 0)      printf("1\n%.7lf\n", -((double)b)/2/a);
    else if (d < 0)       puts("0");
    else if (a > 0)       printf("2\n%.7lf\n%.7lf\n",(-sqrt(d)-b)/2/a, (sqrt(d)-b)/2/a);
    else                  printf("2\n%.7lf\n%.7lf\n",(sqrt(d)-b)/2/a, (-sqrt(d)-b)/2/a);
}
```

Предпочитаю в таких задачах `printf`, чтоб выводить нужное количество знаков *после точки*. В С++ просто внаглую приходится задирать точность - типа

```
cout << setprecision(20);
```

без этого не проходит. Вот на С++, если нужно:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long a, b, c, d;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    d = b*b-4*a*c;

    cout << setprecision(20);
    if (a == 0 && b == 0)    cout << (c ? "0\n" : "-1\n");
    else if (a == 0)         cout << "1\n" << -double(c)/b << "\n";
    else if (d == 0)         cout << "1\n" << -double(b)/2/a << "\n";
    else if (d < 0)          cout << "0\n";
    else if (a > 0)          cout << "2\n" << (-sqrt(d)-b)/2/a << "\n"
                                  << (sqrt(d)-b)/2/a << "\n";
    else                     cout << "2\n" << (sqrt(d)-b)/2/a << "\n"
                                  << (-sqrt(d)-b)/2/a << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Очень вам благодарен