# Задать точность вывода числа с плавающей точкой в ostream

Tags: c++, вывод, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Мотивировано вот этим [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1243787/228791).

Если в С можно легко вывести число с плавающей точкой с конкретным числом знаков именно после точки - через `%.##lf`, то как правильно поступить в C++ с потоками?

`precision` - это же о другом, это всего знакомест. А как правильно указать их число именно после десятичной точки, если заранее значение числа не известно? Не логарифмировать же, чтоб узнать число цифр до точки?

Comment: Использовать [`std::fixed`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/), тогда `precision` будет указывать количество знаков после десятичной точки. [Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/515b9574bc60071c)